# Unexpected syntax error in block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax-error, block, send

I am basically copying one objects information to another. The code or approach in general might not be the most well-thought out, but that's not my problem right now.

This is the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
    original.send("#{attribute}") = edited.send("#{attribute}")
                                   ^
```

What I'm doing is looping through all the attributes of object2 and then "copying" each one to object 1. I could make this specific for each model, but I wanted to have one single implement_changes method, that would work for each class basically. The copy model belongs_to :edited and :original through polymorphic associations.

```
class Copy < ActiveRecord::Base
    def implement_changes
      original = self.original_type.constantize.find(original_id)
      edited = self.edited_type.constantize.find(edited_id)
      accessible_attributes = original_type.constantize.accessible_attributes.to_a.select{|a| a != "slug"}
      accessible_attributes.shift
      accessible_attributes.each do |attribute|
          original.send("#{attribute}") = edited.send("#{attribute}")
      end
      original.save!
    end
```

Why doesn't that block work?? I don't get it. Is the usage of send correct here? It wouldn't let me do original.attribute.

Any help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method name for a setter includes the equals sign, and takes the new value as an argument.  You might try:

`original.send("#{attribute}=", edited.send(attribute))`

Comment: thank you! works fine now and your explaination makes a lot of sense. I was aware of the setter equal signs but messed it up with the two send's.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're not using [ActiveResource::Base#dup](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-i-dup)?

Comment: to make things clearer I didn't fully explain my case. It's not really a copy model, but a vise versa switch of two objects. An edited's attributes replace the original's attributes in the process of a peer review/editing process.